# Python Google Analytics Anti Sampling do hourly call

Tags: python, r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am currently stuck with getting google analytics data via V4 API as sampling rate is very high and the client doesn't want to go to premium account too.

So, I am trying to extract data with multiple dimensions, metrics and thought to combine them.

I successfully connected to GA from python script and able to retrieve data but even in a query with single dimension and metric , my sampling is very high 60%, so I am wondering how to query to get data per hour and combine them

Pls help !!

Answer (score 1):

The `googleAnalyticsR` package for R has built in anti-sampling functionality that will fall back to hourly anti-sampling if daily is not sufficient. Note that the package does not support using Google Analytics filters when hourly anti-sampling is required.

http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/v4.html

Anti-sampling can be achieved by passing the `anti_sample = TRUE` argument to the `google_analytics_4()` function.

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
ga_auth()
id <- "123456789" # Your Google Analytics View ID
unsampled_data_fetch <- google_analytics_4(id, 
                                             date_range = c("2017-01-01","2017-01-31"), 
                                             metrics = c("sessions","bounceRate"), 
                                             dimensions = c("date","landingPagePath","source"),
                                             anti_sample = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes i tried with the above one still it didn't work, any suggestions

Comment: Can you describe how it didn't work? What error are you receiving?

Comment: In the above query if you date_range is long and if you provide anti_smaple=TRUE, it will process for each day and append the result , but if you have large volume of data in a single day - sampling occurs and we cannot do hourly query in a single day to get the data. This is the issue I am facing and it seems there is no way other than premium subscription.

Comment: The above query will resolve to hourly anti-sampling, if required by your query. It is very possible to do hourly queries for a single day. If you are still getting sampled results (i.e. you have > 500,000 sessions in any given hour), then yes, you would need a premium subscription to raise your sampling limits.

Comment: Hi Rhys, can I know how we will be able to do hourly queries - lets say I want to get details on Jan 1 2017 between 2 PM to 3 PM. I think there is no parameter supported to pass time to core reporting API right ??

Comment: You can pass a filter expression `ga:hour==02` if you want only a single specific hour. If you want hourly anti sampling, as per your original question, just pass the `anti_sample = TRUE` argument.